# Spring MVC integration with Rest

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am new to web Services. i have studied Spring MVC and Rest separately. I want to integrate both. I am not finding exact tutorial. Could you please suggest me a tutorial for integration.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to build a rest service with spring.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/

Enjoy!